# Debootstrap on luks encrypted system: initramfs problem

Tags: encryption, lvm, initramfs, debootstrap

since I don't have any external storage I tried to install the new ubuntu version from an already existing system (on a different partition).
So I created an encrypted storage and created a vg and two lv (one for root and one for swap) and then basically followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux) guide for debootstrap.

After starting the image and entering my sda2 password, I get dropped into a busybox with the message that the root directory couldn't be found. Before that, cryptsetup says "lvm fs found but no lvm configured".

I googled the problem and everyone says I should call vgchange or something like that, but I don't seem to have the right module loaded, because vgchange and similar lvm calls aren't found. So what module do I need to load?

Afterwards I hope to boot the system and update-initramfs, so that I only need to solve this problem once...

Thanks for any help,
Niklas

```
cat /etc/fstab
UUID=70a3a6d3-0aaa-4c2b-b988-b71b992484da    /          ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
UUID=f0980e97-655b-4783-bc9a-dbdc8a615439    /boot      ext4    errors=remount-ro defaults 0 1
cat /etc/crypttab 
sda2_crypt    UUID=e9c9de13-c45a-4ba9-a30f-7ce8184073a8   none luks,initramfs
lsblk -o name,uuid
sda                     
├─sda1                  f0980e97-655b-4783-bc9a-dbdc8a615439
└─sda2                  e9c9de13-c45a-4ba9-a30f-7ce8184073a8
  └─sda2_crypt          oFx1zh-Adib-PdNw-imOz-QENx-2vG1-zEv7E6
    ├─vg0-lv0_root      70a3a6d3-0aaa-4c2b-b988-b71b992484da
    └─vg0-lv1_swap      46817e03-ed9d-4105-a074-3645740f1642
```